# Can I use firebase messaging without asking the user for notification permission?

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to be able to get messages via Firebase Messaging API in my web app and I don't need or want to send a notification in the browser at all.
I basically just want to use Firebase Messaging API as if it was a web socket (so that I won't need to create and host my own web socket solution) so in my backend when there's a need to send a message or a new data to a user i'll just do an HTTP request to Firebase Messaging API and they'll send the data to the web app without sending a notification in the browser and without asking for permission to send notification to the user.
BTW I saw some old stackoverflow posts saying it's not possible but they were 1 - 2 years old, so things might have changed.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Nothing has changed, and likely never will without enough people asking for a change (if it's even possible).

Comment: @DougStevenson That sucks.. I think that in android you can do it without asking for permission, IDK why in the web they did it differently...

Comment: Android and web apps operate on completely different permissions systems and user expectations.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yeah I know that, but there should be some shared logic.. I mean if a developer uses firebase notification in the same way I described above on android and they want to do the same thing in the web or IOS or whatever then they won't be able to do it...
And I've heard of many developers using it in that way... which means if they get bigger and want to expect they'd have to ditch firebase...

Comment: There is no shared logic.  They are implemented in completely different languages using completely different environments (web and Android are really nothing alike).  If you have a feature request, please sent it to Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson Yeah, again I know that.. You are missing my point I'm talking about shared logic from a business POV, if U R selling a service you should provide the same functionalities to all the supported platforms, and before you once again say "but they're different platforms and languages" all I'm talking about here is using sockets when the webpage is opened and using the SW when the webpage is closed... this would benefit a lot of developers and allow them to implement their own notification system in their webpages w/o relaying on permissions..
Never mind man..

Comment: Agreed, send feedback to Firebase support.